# my code in eclipse IDE show me this error : Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator<E> should be parameterized :

Tags: java, eclipse

error : Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator should be parameterized

```
<%Iterator itr;%>
<%List data = (List) request.getAttribute("ClientData");
for(itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
        %>enter code here
```

Comment: This is a warning and it tells you everything. You need to add  type to Iteratator

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the signature of the method getAttribute:

```
List<some type> data =  request.getAttribute("ClientData");    
Iterator<some type> itr = data.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
```

Comment: List is a generic type, meaning: It should be parameterized.
For example: if your request.getAttribute return a List<String> you should declare a List<String> and an Iterator<String>
Take a look at generic programming in Java and generics in general